# svndumpfilter exclude does not reduce dump file size

Tags: svn

I have an svn repo that has grown over time and I am trying reduce it by dropping (1) obsolete content and (2) very old history. Right now, I am facing issues in #1, haven't yet started on #2.

I have a targets file that contains top level path prefixes:

```
/.idea
/Demo-1
etc. Also attempted "/.idea/", ".idea", ".idea/" :-(
```

With these filtered out, I expected nearly 50-60% size reduction with:

```
cat current.dump | svndumpfilter exclude --targets targets-file --pattern \
      --drop-empty-revs >filtered.dump
```

But there is no perceptible difference in the two dump filesizes. I built a new repo with the filterd output and took another dump of it - same sizes. There is no error output. It only says:

```
Excluding (and dropping empty revisions for) prefix patterns:
   '/.idea'
   '/Demo-1'
   etc
```

I am on svn 1.8.9 on Linux 3.0.101-0.29-default - an AWS AMI.

Am I missing some step or some options? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. I see empty `--pattern` options. It may be not error, but not good anyway
2. Dump size can be drastically reduced after filtering *only* if there was a lot of adding big files in filtered nodes (or editing binaries - TBT!!!): casual editing will not require a lot of information in dump